# how do i change the font back to default after it was already changed

Tags: java, android

In an app that I'm creating i created an option to change the font of the app, everything works out but i don't know how to set it back to default when the default option is pressed, is there a default ttf file somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

```
 myTextView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: that's great, then accept the answer so others can use it too